# In splitting large class using category, category complains of undeclared selector

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-category

I am working on a view controller that has a long and unpretty view setup method.
For cleanliness, this view setup code is moved to a category, intended only for view setup.

This category references private selectors in the original view controller, and Xcode is showing warnings: `Undeclared selector 'xyz:'`

It seems to me I have these options, none of which seem good:

- Leave the warnings, EYES CLOSED!
- Expose private selectors publicly by declaring in header file
- Declare a second category, which serves as a sub-category to my first category, in the original VC header file

I have gone with the last option, but I still have this feeling like I have to go poo or something. What is the optimal move here?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a declaration to the private method in your category implementation

So in `CustomViewController+ViewSetup.m`

```
@interface CustomViewController (private)

// declare private methods and properties here which you know exist in CustomViewController.m

@end
```

In general though, I think that you are doing with the category is unnecessary. You can clean the code up in the original file and not need a category file to manage and maintain. Not to mention that if you change any of those private method signatures and forget to change it in the category, the compiler will not warn you and you will instead see a crash when you try to call one of those methods.

Comment: I got the idea to split the implementation from the Apple page on categories:

`As well as just adding methods to existing classes, you can also use categories to split the implementation of a complex class across multiple source code files. ...`

You are right about changes in the private method signatures not triggering a compiler warning. Perhaps it is time for me to start using code folding, which I have been avoiding up until now.

Are there other ways to clean the code in the original file without using code folding?